# what is the best approach to load data from Synapse to delta lake?

Tags: azure-data-factory

1. what is the best approach to load data from Synapse to delta lake.
2. We created the data flow to copy data from the synapse to the delta file, so here we have  enabled the "enable staging" option. But after enabling this option all the date fields from the synapse is converting to timestamp in the sink. In case if we remove the "enable staging" option the pipeline execution is taking almost 2 hours other wise half hour.
   3.we have designed the generic pipeline for all the tables, so do we have any option to convert the timestamp to date for the date fields at the run time based on the input parameter.

please suggest if you have any ideas ?

Comment: In its current form, this question is not a great fit for SO. Please refer to [ask] and add what you tried and why that didn't work. On-topic: have a look at [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction).

Comment: i have update the question .Can you please provide your inputs if you have any

Answer (score 0):

Staging will read/load data much faster. But it uses a different data offloading engine in Synapse, so you're getting an implicit type conversion that you don't wish to have. To correct that, add a Derived Column before your Sink in your ADF Data Flow activity. Since your pattern is generic, use the Column Pattern feature to create a generic rule like this:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern

Comment: But the problem here is , in the table we have 2 date columns and 3 datetime columns so if we use this expression all the columns are converting to date fields.

Comment: This pattern will only affect timestamp columns, not date type. Give it a try.

Comment: I am facing issue with the date type columns not the datetime type columns, here all the date type columns are converting to timestamp type columns.

Comment: Exactly. You need to convert them back to dates. That is exactly what my solution above does for you. Try it out.

Comment: But with the above code all  the datetime type columns also will convert to date type columns.so we have data discrepancy with source data